# Best way for shared online sheet like web surface

Tags: excel, windows, google-sheets, worksheet, online-forms

I haven't found a good and simple solution to my problem:

I need either online shared excel file with password protected access or a shared online form like excel adding `names+rows+person` related data.It has to be lockable on a specific date.

Google Sheets is too open and general.  I have to be the admin and be able to lock the Sheet, if the deadline is past and the content in the forms should match.

Also, A simple doodle ak is not a desirable solution. Does Anyone know a product which provides such service? Or Do I have to write a quick web interface?

Comment: Use Google forms with Google Sheets. You can lock the Google sheet past the deadline.

Comment: thank you for you answer! - sorry for my late reply - ill give it a try, so far i didnt find how to add a sheet function (15.03.2018 version) but ill keep looking

Answer (score 1):

how about MS Sharepoint? we can use it for spreadsheet sharing, access control, online check in, edit and then check out, etc.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment and not as an answer

Comment: thank you for you answer! - sorry for my late reply - ill give it a try